# Adding Id to the toastr notification

Tags: javascript, notifications, toastr

Is it possible to Add Id to Toastr Notification?
I need to identify one of several notifications when i close it.
I use this plugin.
https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting question. It doesn't look like you can set an ID on the toastr itself. However, you can modify the button used to close the toastr:

```
toastr.options.closeHtml = '<button id="toastr1closebtn"><i class="icon-off"></i></button>';
```

That might be just as good for what you're trying to do.

I found the option to adjust the close button [here](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr#close-button).

Comment: Thank you, it is really useful in my project.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `toastr.options.closeButton = true;` you can specify a function that should run when you close. That function will be passed the click event. The event can (hopefully) be used to figure out which notification  was closed.

```
toastr.options.onCloseClick = function(event) {
  const closedElement = event.target.parentElement;
  // figure out which notfication was closed based on class, or text, or...
}
```

Perhaps there is a better way, but this is what I found based on [the pretty sparse documentation](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) and some tinkering with the [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6W9URNyyp2ItO4aUWzBB?p=preview) they had.